# Change File locations for iCloud Drive on windows 10

Tags: location, icloud, drive

by default, iCloud Drive on Winows 10 stores files in C:\Users\xyz...\iCloudDrive.
To change the location, one can follow instructions found via google using mklink command e.g.

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/change-icloud-drive-location.html

powershell -> cmd /c mklink /J “C:\Users\xyz...\iCloudDrive” “D:\iCloudDrive”

For me, this is not working.

Every try gives me an additional folder named "iCloud Drive Archive", when I apply in iCloud settings.

Any idea how to change the default location to a different drive
or solution to fix the "iCloud Drive Archive" problem when using mklink command?

Many thanks in advance!